# Convert File::Stat to hash ruby

Tags: ruby

Wondering is there any way to convert the output of

```
File.stat("/tmp/somefile")
=> #<File::Stat dev=0x80a, ino=553198, mode=0100664, nlink=1, uid=1000, gid=1000, rdev=0x0, size=0, blksize=4096, blocks=0, atime=Wed Aug 06 19:04:30 +0530 2014, mtime=Wed Aug 06 19:04:30 +0530 2014, ctime=Wed Aug 06 19:04:30 +0530 2014>
```

to a hash?

Comment: was it originally a ruby object? how is it written to the file?

Comment: @dax sorry i dont get your question? Its just some random file. I created it using `touch /tmp/somefile`. So basically the file is empty. ( or it can be anything else). But when i am getting its stat in ruby using standard class http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html , the output i get is what i want to convert to a hash.

Comment: @shivam, sorry misunderstood you!

Comment: Why http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File/Stat.html don't have `#to_h` . I am thinking.. :-)

Comment: What is the goal here? There's no natural way to do this...

Comment: @Max Im afraid so. In my program I've already taken a completely different approach, however i asked the question just to clarify whether or not its possible (in natural way).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `File::Stat` provides such a method. You could monkey-patch the class like this to provide something similar:

```
File::Stat.class_eval do
  def to_hash
    meths = self.methods - self.class.superclass.instance_methods - [__callee__]
    meths.each_with_object({}) do |meth, acc|
      acc[meth.to_s] = self.send(meth) if self.method(meth).arity == 0
    end
  end
end
```

This pulls all the object's instance methods (and only those defined in `File::Stat`, no ancestors) into a hash. It omits any methods that take arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the prettiest solution, but it works:

```
h = Hash.new
f = File.stat('file.rb')

f.methods[1..17].each do |m|
  h[m] = f.send m
end

h

#=> {:dev=>64770, :dev_major=>253, :dev_minor=>2, :ino=>1315340, :mode=>33204, :nlink=>1, :uid=>1000, :gid=>1000, :rdev=>0, :rdev_major=>0, :rdev_minor=>0, :size=>1553, :blksize=>4096, :blocks=>8, :atime=>2014-02-17 17:43:13 +0100, :mtime=>2014-02-17 17:43:13 +0100, :ctime=>2014-02-17 17:43:13 +0100}
```

Comment: I'd be a little uncomfortable specifying indexes into the list produced by `methods`. I don't think the ordinality is guaranteed to remain the same between Ruby versions.

Comment: I would specify the desired methods explicitly (like an answer @ArupRakshit had here but has since deleted).

Comment: @MarkThomas, agreed, it's really not the best approach, but while ArupRakshit's was a bit more sturdy, who's to say the method names won't change between versions?  I think it's hack-y anyway you slice it.  I like kardeiz's approach to programmatically remove unwanted methods, but I couldn't find a way end up with ONLY the desired methods.